# What do you call someone who livens up the atmosphere

Tags: word-choice

What do you call someone who always livens up the atmosphere at social gatherings, e.g someone who is the most talkative one or helps enliven a party that would otherwise be a boring one. what is the word for this kind of people?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call them "the life of the party".

Comment: +1, but this answer would benefit from an additional sentence. "*Life of the party* is a widely used idiom."